# Non-empty API is not processed forEach (Cannot read property 'forEach' )

Tags: javascript, django-rest-framework

The error is probably stupid, but I'm just learning to program.
I want to display the contents of the API in a tabular form

Local Server: http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/RES/?format=json
API:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"ОАО \"Пеленг\"  ул. Макаенка, 23","adress":"Г. Н-ск","remarks":""}]
```

But the screen remains empty, and in the console - an error:
Well_new.html: 24 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach'

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/RES/').then(function(response) {
    response.json().then(function(data) {
        data.results.forEach(function (item, index) {
            //...
        };
        })
    })
})
```

may not be properly formed API?

Comment: `forEach` works with arrays. Is `data.results` actually an array?

Comment: what is `data.results`?

Comment: Apparently `data` does not have a `results` property on it. You should consider learning to use a debugger where you can set a breakpoint on that line with `data.results.forEach...`. Then you could examine what `data` has.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you need `data.forEach`, not `data.results.forEach`. This also looks like a syntax error, but that's probably from removing some of the inner code.

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrectly used the API.
It should not be `data.results.forEach(...)`, it should be,
`data.forEach(...)`.
Try to refactor your code to the following format and check,

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/RES/?format=json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
      data.forEach(function (item, index) {
            //...
            };
  });
```

Whenever in doubt regarding Web(HTML, CSS, JS) always refer MDN! Here is an explanation of `fetch`,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: OP's way of parsing the response is fine (see here: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/04326cLn/)

Comment: @ChrisG Actually, when the OP originally posted the question the syntax was wrong and he didn't include the entire code. By the time I posted the answer OP edited the question.

Comment: @ChrisG I have anyway edited the answer and it solves the problem